Azure Web PubSub SslStream Error in High-Frequency Direct Messaging Scenario
I'm using Azure Web PubSub in my C# .NET project to stream responses word-by-word directly to individual clients, aiming for real-time interactivity. However, I am facing performance issues and a specific error in direct messaging scenarios with high-frequency messages:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource`TResult`.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Context:
Direct Messaging:
The issue arises specifically in direct messaging (sending messages to individual connections) rather than in group or broadcast messaging.
Latency and Errors:
Alongside this error, there’s noticeable latency that affects the real-time responsiveness of the application, which isn't present when using Azure SignalR under similar conditions.
Setup:
I’ve configured Web PubSub for bidirectional, low-latency communication, akin to WebSocket-like usage, but the error still persists.
Questions:

What are some optimizations or configurations that could mitigate SslStream issues and improve latency in direct messaging with Azure Web PubSub?

Is there a recommended way to handle high-frequency messages in direct messaging without overwhelming the SSL connection layer in Web PubSub?

Would it be advisable to use Azure SignalR for this high-frequency direct messaging while retaining Web PubSub for other uses?


Any insights on optimizing Azure Web PubSub for this type of real-time direct messaging or ways to avoid SslStream issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

According to the docs, it's recommended to use Azure SignalR in dotnet projects for real-time communication that doesn't explicitly rely on features of WebSockets.

@Vivek Rahul refer to this doc Launch the live trace tool

Refer my so for azure we pub and Validate a client certificate in an event handler

use Socket.IO is a real-time messaging between clients and a server.
